# what possible workarounds are there for "only parameterless constructors are support in Linq to Entites"

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In my query I need to return instances of a class that doesn't have a default constructor (specifically this is in a custom Membership provider, and MembershipUser is the culprit)

```
var users = from l in context.Logins
    select new MembershipUser(
        Name,
        l.Username, // username
        l.Id, // provider key
        l.MailTo,
        l.PasswordQuestion,
        l.Notes.FirstOrDefault().NoteText,
        l.IsApproved,
        l.IsLockedOut,
        l.CreatedOn,
        l.LastLoginOn.HasValue ? l.LastLoginOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
        l.LastActivityOn.HasValue ? l.LastActivityOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
        DateTime.MinValue,
        l.LastLockedOutOn.HasValue ? l.LastLockedOutOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue
    );
```

is syntacitally correct, but results in a runtime error as Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Update:  as a workaround I'm now bringing the selection into a List (which resolves the runs the query expression) then I can select the new MembershipUser from that list.

```
var users = (from l in context.Logins
    select new { login = l }).ToList().Select(u => new MembershipUser (
Name,
u.login.Username, // username
u.login.Id, // provider key
u.email.MailTo,
u.login.PasswordQuestion,
u.login.Notes.FirstOrDefault().NoteText,
u.login.IsApproved,
u.login.IsLockedOut,
u.login.CreatedOn,
u.login.LastLoginOn.HasValue ? u.login.LastLoginOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
u.login.LastActivityOn.HasValue ? u.login.LastActivityOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue,
DateTime.MinValue,
u.login.LastLockedOutOn.HasValue ? u.login.LastLockedOutOn.Value : DateTime.MinValue
    );
```

Comment: You don't need to waste the time and memory on materializing to a `List` via `ToList()`.  Just resolve to a disconnected `IEnumerable<T>` using `AsEnumerable()` like Gabe answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is that you need to escape from LINQ to Entities and get to LINQ to Objects, which allows arbitrary method calls. The `AsEnumerable` extension method does this for you.
How about this:

```
var users = from l in context.Logins.AsEnumerable() 
    select new MembershipUser( 
        Name, 
        l.Username, // username 
        l.Id, // provider key 
        l.MailTo, 
        l.PasswordQuestion, 
        l.Notes.FirstOrDefault().NoteText, 
        l.IsApproved, 
        l.IsLockedOut, 
        l.CreatedOn, 
        l.LastLoginOn ?? DateTime.MinValue, 
        l.LastActivityOn ?? DateTime.MinValue, 
        DateTime.MinValue, 
        l.LastLockedOutOn ?? DateTime.MinValue 
    );
```

Comment: No because "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"

Comment: Makes total sense now.  Thanks.

Comment: Won't this mean that any `where` parts won't get converted to a SQL WHERE clause? Won't it just pull all Logins down and then LINQ->Objects takes over for the `where` filtering?

Comment: @SeanHanley: You put all of your filtering/grouping/joining/sorting logic before the `AsEnumerable`. The last two steps in you query are `.AsEnumerable().Select(r => new ...)`.